# Change input text to select options & vice versa

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons. On first buttons click, I needs to change input text type to select box & on second buttons click, change the select box to input text type through Javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What options would you even put within the select box/

Comment: @JoshMein, I have 'Disease' select box. When I select the disease like 'Obesity', the input type must be changed to text & when I select the disease like 'Depression', the input type must be changed to select box with 'Not anymore, Controlled, Tolerable, Severe' values filled inside select box.

Comment: @Bergi, Rocket 
<select id='disease1CurrentValue'></select/>
var obj = document.getElementById('disease1CurrentValue');
obj.setAttribute('type', 'text');

Comment: You can't do that.  A `<select>` element is not an `<input>` element, and therefore doesn't have a `type` attribute (which I'm 70% sure you can't change once the `<input>` is in the DOM).  One way is to make both types of elements and show/hide them when necessary.

Comment: Why dont you have both and just hide and show as necessary?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot @JoshMein, @Bergi, @Rocket for your time & suggestions. It helped me a lot.  I also tried in diff way as follow.

---

```
function changeToText() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('disease1CurrentObject');
  document.getElementById('divDisease1Current').removeChild(document.getElementById(obj));
  var element = document.createElement('input');
  element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  element.setAttribute('value', 'myVal');
  element.setAttribute('id', 'myId');
  document.getElementById('divDisease1Current').appendChild(element); 
}
function changeToSelect() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('disease1CurrentObject');
  document.getElementById('divDisease1Current').removeChild(obj));
  var element = document.createElement('select');
  element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  element.setAttribute('value', 'myVal');
  element.setAttribute('id', 'myId');
  document.getElementById('divDisease1Current').appendChild(element);
}
```

**& 1 more, setAttribute() is not supported by IE version less than 8 or 8.**